# KnexJS Character Encoding

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

my question is if it is somehow possible to change the character encoding of KnexJS to utf8mb4. It seems to default to utf8.

When I try to create a table on the current KnexJS Version inside on a NodeJS Server via

```
db.schema.createTable('testtable', table => {
  table.increments('id');
  table.string('foo').unique();
});
```

KnexJS throws an error, saying that the specified key was too long. This happens due to KnexJS's varchar length defaulting to 255. The maximum length for a utf8mb4 field is 191 characters.

Is there an option to tell KnexJS what character encoding to use (thus changing the length of varchar fields to 191) or do I have to set the length of every varchar field to 191 myself by passing it as the second parameter on `table.string(..., 191)`?

The error message:

```
Error creating testtable table { Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
at Packet.asError (C:\Users\nicoe\WebstormProjects\worktrackr\backend\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:713:13)
at Query.Command.execute (C:\Users\nicoe\WebstormProjects\worktrackr\backend\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:22)
at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\nicoe\WebstormProjects\worktrackr\backend\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:515:28)
at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\nicoe\WebstormProjects\worktrackr\backend\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:94:16)
at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\nicoe\WebstormProjects\worktrackr\backend\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:77:14)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nicoe\WebstormProjects\worktrackr\backend\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:102:29)
at Socket.emit (events.js:159:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:252:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:598:20)


code: 'ER_TOO_LONG_KEY',
  errno: 1071,
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes' }
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I think the proper solution so that 255 is a valid value is to change the underlying encoding scheme for knex while performing the migration but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the fault with knex that you are getting that error. It's that you are creating the string column of length 255, which is the default if you don't pass any parameters.

You can change the default length of the column by:

```
db.schema.createTable('testtable', table => {
  table.increments('id');
  table.string('foo', 300).unique(); // 300 length
});
```

Or if you want to store really large text, you can use:

```
db.schema.createTable('testtable', table => {
  table.increments('id');
  table.text('foo').unique();
});
```

Comment: I know that giving the string function a second parameter can set the length as already mentioned in my question. What I am interested in is, if it's possible to default the string() function varchar length to some other length than 255 (for example via config) or not.
Maybe creating a const with the length of 191 and passing it into every string() function could be another approach to keep the code easily maintainable. But this doesnt seem to be the best workaround.

Comment: You can use configs and let the various length be there. You can require the config in the migration and do it that way, but i don't really see the point in that.

Comment: Well the point is that I only have one place to set the length of the varchars when I do it that way. Using your approach, changing the collation which sometimes results in another maximum key length (like in my Question) doesnt have to be done for every "string" field I want to create in my database.